# A more efficient way for my program to write every billionth combination?

Tags: c++, permutation, combinations, combinatorics

So the following program generates combinations on characters in this master string, which you will see in the program. First the program generates all of the 48 choose 12 combinations, and then all the way up to 48 choose 19.

The problem is that the total number of combinations is 65 trillion, which is not possible to compute in a reasonable amount of time. I thought, "Ok, well I will just write every billionth one to the file." Well, that will also take a ton of time, because the program still has to count to 65 trillion, even if it only writes every billionth combination.

Is there anything I could modify in my program to avoid this having to count to an extraordinary large number, but still write every billionth combination to a file?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename Iterator>
bool next_combination(const Iterator first, Iterator k, const Iterator last)
{
   if ((first == last) || (first == k) || (last == k))
      return false;
   Iterator i1 = first;
   Iterator i2 = last;
   ++i1;
   if (last == i1)
      return false;
   i1 = last;
   --i1;
   i1 = k;
   --i2;
   while (first != i1)
   {
      if (*--i1 < *i2)
      {
         Iterator j = k;
         while (!(*i1 < *j)) ++j;
         std::iter_swap(i1,j);
         ++i1;
         ++j;
         i2 = k;
         std::rotate(i1,j,last);
         while (last != j)
         {
            ++j;
            ++i2;
         }
         std::rotate(k,i2,last);
         return true;
      }
   }
   std::rotate(first,k,last);
   return false;
}

unsigned long long count = 0;

int main()
{
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("m = 8.txt");

  string s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnop";

  for (int i = 12; i <= 19; i++)
  {
    std::size_t comb_size = i;

    do
    { 
      if (count == 0)
        myfile << std::string(s.begin(),s.begin() + comb_size) << std::endl;

      if (++count % 1000000000 == 0)
        myfile << std::string(s.begin(),s.begin() + comb_size) << std::endl;

    }while(next_combination(s.begin(),s.begin()+ comb_size,s.end()));
  }

  myfile.close();

  cout << "Done!" << endl;

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure optimizing away a simple counter increment matters in the presence of all those loops inside `next_combination`? Wouldn't it be better to compute ony every billionth combination from the start?

Comment: Well, a simple division by 3600 seconds implies that gives 18,055,555,555 combinations per second. Way too much. This exercise was designed to make brute force unfeasible.

Comment: I don't see how you came up with 65 trillion.  48 choose 12 is about 69.7 billion.  48 choose 19 is about 11.5 trillion.  Are you generating combinations, or permutations?  Combinations are unique, where as permutations consider order to be important.  Total number of combinations in 3 choose 2 would be 3.  Total number of permutations of 3 items in 2 locations would be 3 * 3 = 9.

Comment: He is generating all 48 chose 12 then all 48 chose 13 ... then 48 chose 19

Comment: So, to calculate the total number of combinations from both sets, they can be calculated by simply adding them together: 11,500,000,000,000 + 69,700,000,000 = 11,569,700,000,000.  So, I come up with about 11.5697 trillion total number of combinations.  Where does the 65 trillion come from.  There is a solution to this problem, but I just want to make sure that the problem is combinations and not permutations before posting it.

Comment: Bob - I apologize, the the number of combinations (order doesn't matter) is 27 trillion, not 65 trillions, which I'm not sure where I got that from. 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%2848+choose+i%29+from+i+%3D+12+to+19

Comment: sorry, does it matter the way you are finding the nth permutation?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter the way we are finding the nth combination (NOT permutation), as long as we are consistent.

Answer (score 4):

I've got a simple transformation to use a different library which is about 36X faster than yours.  It is still brute force.  But while on my machine I'm estimating your code will take 418 days to complete, my code will take only about 3.65 days.  Still outrageously long.  But it gets it down to a long weekend.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "../combinations/combinations"

using namespace std;

unsigned long long count = 0;

int main()
{
  ofstream myfile("m = 8.txt");

  string s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnop";

  for (int i = 12; i <= 19; i++)
     for_each_combination(s.begin(), s.begin() + i, s.end(),
        [&](std::string::const_iterator f, std::string::const_iterator l) -> bool
        {
          if (::count++ % 1000000000 == 0)
            myfile << std::string(f, l) << std::endl;
          return false;
        });

  myfile.close();

  cout << "Done!" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Cutting the number of tests on `count` in the inner loop was a 15% performance increase.

"../combinations/combinations" refers to this library:

http://howardhinnant.github.io/combinations.html

The link includes a description and full source code.

This test program can also easily be modified to count the total number of combinations:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "../combinations/combinations"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
  string s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnop";
  unsigned long long count = 0;
  for (int i = 12; i <= 19; i++)
     count += count_each_combination(s.begin(), s.begin() + i, s.end());

  cout << "Done! " << count << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
Done! 27189132782091
```

The code is open source with a boost license (it is not part of the boost library).  Feel free to use it.

Comment: +1 for your effort, although I do not believe brute force was the intent of this exercise. Just increasing the problem size a bit, say 49 instead of 48 and the days become weeks.

Comment: Hey, I want to say a huge thanks for taking the time to help me Howard. I am now running your code, but the thing is, it seems to only write one combination every couple of minutes. 

I estimate it would take around 30 days to run. There are approx 27 trillion combinations, and since we are writing every billionth, that leaves 27 thousand to write to disc. The program is going no faster than one combination written per minute. 

Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: Did you compile with full speed optimizations on?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean by full speed optimization, I'm compiling in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. I tried the "build" version and the "release" version, but both are about the same speed. Which optimizations in particular do you mean?

Comment: I used clang++ with -O3 for this answer.  Sorry, I'm not familiar with the optimization options for VS.  I was getting a write once every 11.6 seconds on a 2.8 GHz Core i5 iMac.

Comment: That's really bizarre, I'm getting a write once every 1 to 2 minutes. I'm using maximum speed optimization. Do you really think there's that much of a difference between Clang and VS that it would cause such a discrepancy? And do you know how I could resolve this? Once again, thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't have an explanation.  One thing you might try is to pass char* instead of string::iterator to for_each_combination.  You can do this with &s[0], etc. and you'll need to adjust the functor to take const char* too.  I would not expect this to make a significant difference.  But I also would not expect the results you're seeing.

Comment: 64-bit integer division is quite slow even on modern machines. Maybe you can shave off a few hours with `if (::count++ == 1000000000){ count = 0; … }`, though you will need to pull the first iteration out of the loop, if you want its results as well.

Comment: @DavidFoerster:  That's a good suggestion.  However I tried that before posting my answer, and at least for me, it turned out to not make a measurable difference.  I was a little surprised by that result, as I quite agree with you.  I did not investigate it further, and may well have overlooked something.

Comment: Your combinatorics library is really nice. However, it would be greatly enhanced if you also provided ranking and unranking functions (using e.g. lex and colex order) for permutations and combinations. E.g. Mathematica (not the quickest of languages) has this functionality and I just computed this in 3.5 hours (24X speedup over your already 36X speedup!). With an optimized C++ implementation, I guess that this computation can be done in a matter of minutes. E.g. chess endgame databases use these computations for random access to combinations (which correspond to pieces on the board).

Comment: @TemplateRex:  Sounds like an interesting and useful challenge.  I don't know if I'll ever find time to do something like that.  But I agree with you, this would be a great enhancement.

Comment: In what order do you generate your combinations? Lex or colex or something else? I have some code that I could try to generalize.

Comment: I don't know.  I'm under-educated in this area.  I shot from the hip, and I don't use the element's operator== or operator<.

Comment: I wrote a special solution based on your beloved bitvectors ;-) See my answer at the bottom of this page.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I wrote before for finding the kth permutation of a given string. I think my idea is similar to @Tarik that we don't need to list all the permutations before the kth.

```
string getPermutation(string s, int k) {
    string res;
    int n = s.size();
    int total = 1, digits = n - 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
        total *= i;
    while (res.size() < n)
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (int m = 1; m < (int) ceil(k * 1.0 / total); ++m)
            i++;
        res += s[i];
        s.erase(s.begin() + i); // erase from string is not a good idea:)
        k = (k % total == 0) ? total : k % total;
        total = (total == 1) ? 1 : total / digits--;
    }
    return res;
}
```

It works well for short string. For example `getPermutation("12345", 37)` will return `24135`.

But for your string `s` with length `48`, the variable `total` will overflow even with type `long long`. So we need to do extra work handling this.

My code is somewhat hard to understand:) <del>You may improve on my code.</del> I hope this will help you.

**UPDADE:** I realize that what you need is **combination** not **permutation**. I totally went wrong! Forget my code:)

Comment: +1 for providing code. Yet, 65 trillion = 6.5E13 bellow the maximum of a signed 64 bit number = 2 ^ 63 - 1 = 9.223372e+18

Comment: @Tarik Thank you and sorry, I misunderstood the problem. My code is all about permutation not combination...--|

Answer (score 1):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinadic there is an algorithm to compute directly the k-th combination. You need first to store Pascal's triangle. If you need some code example, you can have a look at (Python language) https://github.com/sagemath/sagelib/blob/master/sage/combinat/choose_nk.py.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bitvector to speed up some of the computations, adapted from the [bit-twiddling pages](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Traversing+Subsets+of+a+Set#Subsets%20with%20equal%20Cardinality) of Chess Programming Wiki.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdint>

using U64 = uint64_t;

// generate the next integer with the same number of bits as c
U64 next_combination(U64 c) 
{
    auto const smallest = c & -c;
    auto const ripple = c + smallest;
    auto ones = c ^ ripple;
    ones = (ones >> 2) / smallest;
    return ripple | ones;
}

// generate all integers with k of the first n bits set
template<class Function>
void for_each_combination(std::size_t n, std::size_t k, Function fun)
{
    U64 y;
    auto const n_mask = (1ULL << n) - 1; // mask with all n bits set to 1
    auto const k_mask = (1ULL << k) - 1; // mask with first k bits set to 1

    auto x = k_mask; fun(x);
    for (; (y = next_combination(x) & n_mask) > x; x = y) fun(y);
}

int main() 
{
    auto const million = 1000000ULL;
    auto count = U64 { 0 };
    for (auto i = 12; i < 20; ++i) {
        for_each_combination(48, i, [&](U64 c) {
        /*if (count++ & million == 0) std::cout << std::dec << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(8) << (count - 1) / million << ": " << std::hex << std::showbase << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(16) << c << "\n";*/
            ++count;
        });
    }
    std::cout << count << "\n";
}
```

On a single core inside a virtualbox of my Xeon E5-1650 @3.2 Ghz, my best estimate is that it will take 3.52 days to increment the counter 2.7e13 times (not generating the output itself). It only works for subsets B(n, k) with n < 64, unless you use some 128-bit integer class.

Given a bitvector that has `k` out of `n` bits set to 1, it is a straightforward matter to map that to the original sequence of chars or any other type and print whatever combination is required. For sequences that do not have random iterator access, it is of course more expensive than Howard Hinnant's approach.

Answer (score -1):

if you don't care what the actual count is, you use a 32-bit int, which will still let you know what you hit 1-billion.

Comment: Other optimizations could be used such as using efficient inline code to swap or shift characters, to not avail in view of the size of the problem.